# Python - how do I display an updating value on one line and not scroll down the screen

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, scroll, output

I have a python script which receives values in real-time. My script prints the values as they are received and currently, each update is printed to the screen and the output scrolls down e.g.

```
Update 1
Update 2
Update 3
...
```

Is it possible to have each new value overwrite the previous value on the output screen so that the values don't scroll? e.g.

```
Update 1
```

When Update 2 is received the print statement would update the output screen to:

```
Update 2
```

and so on...

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python 2.7, the print function will not allow an `end` parameter, and `print 'Update %d\r'` will also print a newline character.

Here is the same example @elethan gave for python2.7. Note it uses the `sys.stdout` output stream:

```
import sys
import time
output_stream = sys.stdout

for i in xrange(10):
    output_stream.write('Update %s\r' % i)
    output_stream.flush()
    time.sleep(5)
# Optionally add a newline if you want to keep the last update.
output_stream.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 17):

You can pass `end='\r'` to the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function. `'\r'` represents a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) in Python. In Python 3 for example:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print('Update %d' % i, end='\r')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Here `time.sleep(5)` is just used to force a delay between prints. Otherwise, even though everything is being printed and then overwritten, it will happen so fast that you will only see the final value `'Update 9'`. In your code, it sounds like there is a natural delay while some processes is running, using `time.sleep()` will not be necessary.

Comment: this will not work on Linux environments, you need to update print statement as shown here on consoles/Linux `print('', end=f'\rUpdate {i}')`

Comment: Would this work if subthread print additional values into the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your code which prints the updated list in `write_num` function,
You can have a function called `show_updated_list()`.
Hoping the `clear()` every time should resolve this issue:

```
def show_updated_list():
    self.clear()
    write_num()
```